# Powershell - Export Mailbox Information

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

So I have the following script - whereby I want to export both Get-Mailbox information, and Get-MailboxStatistics information as I understand they both handle different aspects of the mailbox with regards to the information we can export about.

```
Get-Mailbox -Server Server01 -ResultSize unlimited |
 Where {$_.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults -eq $false} |
   ft DisplayName,IssueWarningQuota,ProhibitSendQuota,@{label="TotalItemSize(MB)";expression={(Get-MailboxStatistics $_).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}}
```

Problem 1: is I get no information in the TotalItemSize field when I run the script
Problem 2: If I add `| Export-CSV C:\test.csv` I get garbage!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting garbage on the export-csv because you're trying to export format-table data.  Trade that format-table for select-object and it'll work better.

```
$MBXs = Get-Mailbox -Server Server01 -ResultSize Unlimited |
 Where {$_.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults -eq $false} 

 &{
 foreach ($MBX in $MBXs)
  {$MBX | select DisplayName,IssueWarningQuota,ProhibitSendQuota,@{label="TotalItemSize(MB)";expression={(Get-MailboxStatistics $MBX).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}}}
  }|export-csv mbxquotas.csv
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I also get the Quota to display as MB and not GB like the TotalItemSize?